# Installing RLdev tools on Linux

Tags: ocaml

When installing Haeleth's [RLdev](http://dev.haeleth.net/rldev.shtml) I got the error:

```
$ ./configure && omake
........
File "pa_matches.ml", line 24, characters 2-6:
Parse error: Deprecated syntax, the grammar module is expected
Error while running external preprocessor
Command line: camlp4 pa_o.cmo pa_op.cmo pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo pr_dump.cmo 'pa_matches.ml' > /home/.../tmp/ocamlpp4e8738

*** omake error:
   File rlc/OMakefile: lines 26:4-27:88
   command terminated with code 2: ocamlc -c -pp 'camlp4 pa_o.cmo pa_op.cmo pa_extend.cmo q_MLast.cmo pr_dump.cmo' -I /usr/lib/ocaml/camlp4 gramlib.cma pa_matches.ml -o pa_matches.cmo
```

File `pa_matches.ml` contains only following code:

```
Line 22: open Pcaml
Line 23: EXTEND
Line 24:   expr: LEVEL "expr1"
Line 25:     [[ v = expr; "matches"; p = patt -> <:expr< match $v$ with [ $p$ -> True | _ -> False ] >> ]];
Line 26: END
```

In the INSTALL file specified OCaml version 3.09 but 4.01 installed.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml 3.09 is incompatible to OCaml 4.01. This especially applies to camlp4. With OCaml 3.10 a new, backward incompatible version of camlp4 was introduced.

That's probably the reason, why pa_matches.ml doesn't  compile. It uses the old camlp4.

Comment: OCaml 4.01 can still compile most of the code I've seen written against 3.09 if the code does not rely on syntax extensions.  Unfortunately the update to camlp4 in 3.10 was a major breaking change for any syntax extensions.  So even if the rest of the code is 4.01-ready, anything relying on a syntax extension is effectively incompatible.